# Extra line before aligned equations when using adjustwidth

Tags: amsmath, changepage

I am trying to use adjustwidth environment on align environment to make it so my equations will not get cut off by the margin. When I do this, it shifts the equations as desired, but it also introduces a new blank line before my equations which I want to remove.

```
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{changepage}
To test this we have 
\begin{align*} 
asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
\end{align*}
and then we also have
\begin{adjustwidth}{-3cm}{0cm}
\begin{align*} 
asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
\end{align*}
\end{adjustwidth}
```

Answer (score 1):

Added vertical space when using `adjustwidth` environment you can remove by adding  `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` after `\begin{adjustwidth}...` and before `\end{adjustidth`. To make shorter notation you can define new environment as is done in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{wide}[2]%
    {\begin{adjustwidth}{#1}{#2}
     \vspace{-\baselineskip}}
    {\end{adjustwidth}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{gather*}
asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf\\
asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasd
\end{gather*}
and then we also have
\begin{adjustwidth}{-33mm}{0cm}
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}
\begin{gather*}
asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
\end{gather*}
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}
\end{adjustwidth}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{wide}{-33mm}{0cm}
\begin{gather*}
asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasd\end{gather*}
\end{wide}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Advantage of this solution is that you can use any of `amsmath`/`mathtools`/`empheq` math environments (as you can see in above MWE)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that adds unwanted space. Here's a version that's free from the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{pushequationleft}{mo}
 {$$\hspace{-#1}\IfValueT{#2}{\begin{#2ed}}}
 {\IfValueT{#2}{\end{#2ed}}\hspace{1000pt minus 1fill}$$}

\begin{document}

\noindent\makebox[0pt][r]{\vrule width 3cm height 0.4pt}
\begin{pushequationleft}{3cm}
asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
\end{pushequationleft}
\lipsum[1][1-4]
\begin{pushequationleft}{3cm}[align]
asdf &= asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf \\
asdf &= asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
\end{pushequationleft}
\lipsum[2][1-4]
\begin{pushequationleft}{3cm}[gather]
asdf = asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf \\
asdf = asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
\end{pushequationleft}
\lipsum[3][1-4]

\end{document}
```

The optional argument can be `align` or `gather`, for multiline displays.

The first line shows that the equation is pushed exactly 3cm to the left.

[image]

If you want that the equation sticks the same amount on either side:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{pushequationleft}{o}
 {$$\hspace{1000pt minus 1fill}\IfValueT{#1}{\begin{#1ed}}}
 {\IfValueT{#1}{\end{#1ed}}\hspace{1000pt minus 1fill}$$}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4][1-4]
\begin{pushequationleft}
asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
\end{pushequationleft}
\lipsum[1][1-4]
\begin{pushequationleft}[align]
asdf &= asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf \\
asdf &= asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
\end{pushequationleft}
\lipsum[2][1-4]
\begin{pushequationleft}[gather]
asdf = asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf \\
asdf = asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
\end{pushequationleft}
\lipsum[3][1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

In any case, avoid using `align*` for single equations.

Comment: I am getting undefined control sequence. Also, most of the equations are multi line. Currently I am using my own hacky solution of adding vspace after the adjustwidth environment